# Resetting input boxes in react frozen after setting state

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I Found a nice way to clear input values using setState in react. Unfortunately once the value is set to "" it is cleared and will not allow you to type in the boxes anymore. Does anyone know how to fix this or can refer me to a post where this is solved? Thanks

```
  
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  

  const handleAddTask = () => {
 task.title && setTasks([...tasks, task]);
    setInputValue({ val: "" });
  };


<input
              value={inputValue.val}
              name="title"
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              className="input-values"
              type="text"
            ></input>

<button onClick={handleAddTask} className="add-task">
            Add Task
          </button>
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code for context, what is `handleOnChange` is doing?

Comment: Your default state value `useState("")` is string, but your JSX works with it as an object `value={inputValue.val}`